# Há limite de tamanho no writerow de csv?

Tags: python, csv

Vou criar um CSV de 1.341 linhas (com cabeçalho). Em Python 3 usei os comandos de csv, mas o arquivo criado tem 1.282 linhas

Os dados das linhas são extraídos de 1.340 PDFs, dos metadados. Criei uma lista e um print para checar, está extraindo tudo certo

O código do CSV:

```
import csv

conjunto = open('emendas_autores.csv', mode='w', encoding='latin_1')

resultado = csv.DictWriter(conjunto, fieldnames=["Arquivo", "Autor", "Assunto", "Data_Criacao", "Data_Moficacao"])

resultado.writeheader()

def salva_csv():
    print("+")
    print (arquivo)
    print (author)
    print (subject)
    print (creation_date)
    print(mod_date)
    print("+")
    resultado.writerow({'Arquivo': arquivo,
                   'Autor': author, 
                   'Assunto': subject,
                   'Data_Criacao': creation_date,
                   'Data_Moficacao': mod_date})
    return
```

Depois vai a iteração que extrai os dados dos PDFs e chama a função `salva_csv()` e cada arquivo

Por favor, alguém saberia o que pode estar errado para parar em 1.282 linhas? Há limite de tamanho no writerow de csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei exatamente como a biblioteca do csv funciona, mas você poderia usar também a bilbioteca pandas pra ler e salvar csvs (não sei se no seu caso é melhor).

Você poderia fazer

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv('emendas_autores.csv')

dados = {
    'autor': ['autor1', 'autor2', 'autor3'],
    'assunto': ['assunto1', 'assunto2', 'assunto3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dados)

df.to_csv('nome_meu_csv.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Obrigado! Mas no meu caso é o 'emendas_autores.csv' que está sendo criado com linhas a menos, é ele que preciso criar completo antes

Comment: com with consegui:
header = True
with open('emendas_autores.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # se precisarmos gravar o cabeçalho...
    if header is True:
        # gravamos o cabeçalho
        writer.writerow(tabela_final[0])
        # marcamos que não é mais preciso gravar o cabeçalho
        header = False
    # gravamos o restante das linhas no CSV
    writer.writerows(tabela_final[1:])